# How to move buttons created during code with a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, button, timer

For the  code i am currently writing, i have a timer that spawns buttons around the edges of the form. I would like the buttons to then  move towards the center of the screen--think asteroids-- but don't know how to make that happen. Thanks in advance for any help!
my code so far:

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer newtimer = new Timer();
        newtimer.Interval = 100;
        newtimer.Start();





        Button enemybutton = new Button();
        int sidepick = rnd.Next(1, 5);
        if(sidepick == 1)
        {
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1, 15);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1, 700);
        }

      else  if (sidepick == 2)
        {
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1, 15);
        }

       else if (sidepick == 3)
        {
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1,1315);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(650,665);
        }
        if (sidepick == 4)
        {
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1300,1315);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1,650);
        }
        enemiesSpawned++;
        if(enemiesSpawned == levelsBeat)
        {
            levelsBeat++;
            enemiesSpawned = 0;
            timer1.Stop();
        }


        enemybutton.Height = 64;
        enemybutton.Width = 64;
        Controls.Add(enemybutton);

    }
```

Comment: Your timer should never be created/started inside the tick event handler.  On what event do you want to be moving the controls?  How fast do you want to move the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to collect all the spawned buttons in a `List` for future reference.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<Button> ButtonList = new List<Button>();
private void timer_spawn_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button enemybutton = new Button();
    enemybutton.Click += Enemybutton_Click;

    int sidepick = rnd.Next(1, 5);

    switch (sidepick)
    {
        case 1:
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1, 15);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1, 700);
            break;
        case 2:
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1, 15);
            break;
        case 3:
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1, 1315);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(650, 665);
            break;
        case 4:
            enemybutton.Left = rnd.Next(1300,1315);
            enemybutton.Top = rnd.Next(1, 650);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    enemybutton.Height = 64;
    enemybutton.Width = 64;
    Controls.Add(enemybutton);

    ButtonList.Add(enemybutton);  

    enemiesSpawned++;
    if(enemiesSpawned == levelsBeat)
    {
        levelsBeat++;
        enemiesSpawned = 0;
        timer1.Stop();
    }

}
```

Then you could use a second timer for the moving part and access the buttons in the `List` to move them. Just calculate a new `Location` for each button:

```
private void timer_move_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    foreach (var button in ButtonList)
    {
        button.Location = CalculateMove(button.Location);
    }
}

private Point CalculateMove(Point currentLocation)
{
    Point center = new Point(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2);
    Point moveDestination = new Point();
    int stepsize = 20;

    moveDestination.X = currentLocation.X < center.X ? currentLocation.X + stepsize : currentLocation.X - stepsize;
    moveDestination.Y = currentLocation.Y < center.Y ? currentLocation.Y + stepsize : currentLocation.Y - stepsize;

    return moveDestination;
}
```

This is a very simple movement calculation. But for the sake of simply moving it works. You can fiddle out a nicer one I guess.